# Trying to auto submit form with jQuery to ajax function failed, with no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have tried various ways to do that, I am sure there some simple work around...trying to solve it for the last 2 hours still no luck..or errors..:(
Here I am creating new form elements with values generated from json and jquery function..

```
var prevNewWidth = '<input type="hidden" value="' + prevNewWidth + '" name=prevNew />';
var sliderValue = '<input type="hidden" value="' + sliderValue + '" name="thisNew" />';
var thisCellId = '<input type="hidden" value="' + item.thisCellId + '" name="thisCellId" />';
var prevCellId = '<input type="hidden" value="' + item.prevCellId + '" name="prevCellId" />';

$('#sliderForm').append(prevNewWidth);
$('#sliderForm').append(sliderValue);
$('#sliderForm').append(thisCellId);
$('#sliderForm').append(prevCellId);
$('#sliderForm').submit(ajax);
```

This is my ajax function..

```
function ajax() {    
   $.ajax({            
      //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
      url: "cellWidthUpdate.php",    

      //method
      type: "POST",

      //pass the data            
      data: cellNewWidth.serialize(),        

      //success
      success: function (html) { 
         alert(html);       
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
         var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
         alert(err.Message);
      }         
   })
};
```

Comment: Coming back to one of my first questions at Stackoverflow. Now I would like to ask the question that was bothering me for years, who and why downvoted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not auto-submitting the form (at least not in the code you've provided). `.submit()` is just attaching an *event handler* to `#sliderForm`'s submit event. If you want your `ajax` method to be called, you must either trigger the submit event, or - even prettier - you can use jQuery's `.triggerHandler` (http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) to invoke your handler without triggering the event's default behaviour:

```
$('#sliderForm').triggerHandler('submit');
```